# Block ratio in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Giving an altitude y, what is (or how can I find, or even is possible to find) the block ration in Minecraft (or in a given world, possibly not the *entire* world, but also in function of the *already generated* world)?

By block ratio I mean given a particular block X what is the percentage of the amount of X in an altitude y that we can find compared to the total number of blocks.

By *block* I also mean fluids, although I can be happy with an answer excluding fluids.

Comment: what? i am just confused

Comment: World generation really depends on the seed given. We can't really be sure what the block ratio of each `y` since there are usually some hills and mountains, and there are also caves. It's obvious that anything below 0 is a void (well, except for 1.17+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Minecraft 1.16.4 resource distrubution by altitude](https://meeples10.github.io/resource-distribution.html) provides a table and a csv file of counts of all block types per altitude over a large example world; it's not too difficult to convert these to percentages e.g. in a spreadsheet. It also contains tools (server plugins) to generate your own table for given area of a specific world.